# Can't replicate awful Metal rendering bug which causes App Rejection

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoa, mac-app-store, metal

I have a Metal-powered app that works just fine on my dev Mac, my main Mac and my friend's Mac. However when I send it to Apple, they get this awful glitch while resizing window. Here are their screenshots:

[image]

What on the Earth can cause that only on their macs?

**Edit:** I was able to retrieve system info from Apple engineers.

[image][image]

So I guess the problem is with either NVidia driver or non-Retina screen. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with different graphic cards used in their Macs (I'm not an expert in this field). I think I would first go into a nearby Apple Store (if you have one) and try the app on every Mac available. This could be a starting point in diagnosing the issue.

Comment: Also check if Retina/non-Retina might be the trigger.

Comment: Yep, it seems like non-Retina is the problem, how one can fix that?